# How do I cast an MFC window handle to a System.Windows.Window

Tags: c++, wpf, mfc, interop

I'm attempting to host a WPF Window under an MFC application. I've created a CCustomEditor class to wrap the WPF window. It has the following create method.

```
BOOL CCustomEditor::Create(LPCTSTR lpszWindowName, DWORD dwStyle,
    const RECT& rect, CWnd* pParentWnd)
{ 
        if (objInterop == NULL) 
        {
            DialogWindow ^myWindow = gcnew DialogWindow(pParentWnd);
            CUnmanagedCustomEditor *objProxy = new CUnmanagedCustomEditor();
            objInterop = objProxy;
            System::String ^strClassName = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String ^>(lpszWindowName);
            HwndSourceParameters^ sourceParams = gcnew HwndSourceParameters(strClassName);
            sourceParams->PositionX = rect.left;
            sourceParams->PositionY = rect.top;
            sourceParams->ParentWindow = System::IntPtr(pParentWnd->GetSafeHwnd());
            sourceParams->WindowStyle = dwStyle;
            objProxy->m_hwndSource= gcnew HwndSource(*sourceParams);
            objProxy->m_wpfUC                   = myWindow;     
            objProxy->m_hwndSource->RootVisual  = objProxy->m_wpfUC; 
            // we need to attach a handle since it is a window control
            Attach((HWND) objProxy->m_hwndSource->Handle.ToPointer());  
        }

    return TRUE;
}
```

The problem I'm encountering is with this:

```
DialogWindow ^myWindow = gcnew DialogWindow(pParentWnd);
```

I realize that a CWnd can't be treated directly as a System.Windows.Window but I'm not sure what kind of conversion is necessary.

Comment: After banging my head against the wall for quite awhile, I'm thinking this might not be possible. I was intending to just have a "bare" WPF window but I'm thinking the best way to do this is to use the User Control that already makes up the entirety of the DialogWindow contents.

Comment: Reading following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744829.aspx might help you.

Comment: Also, check out http://binarysculpting.com/2012/03/04/hosting-a-wpf-control-inside-a-mfc-window-and-making-the-keyboard-work/